# Attribute table is missing in raster after using extract by mask tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-table, extract-by-mask

Every time I use the extract by mask tool, the rasters that are created don't have an attribute table (i.e it's greyed out). Does anyone know what is causing this and why these rasters essentially no longer have any values associated with them? Is there a way to get around this issue? I am using ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS for Desktop or something else? There is an **edit** button you can use to clarify your question with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

Since extract by mask creates an entirely new raster, I wouldn't necessarily expect it to preserve any attribute table associated with the original. The actual *values* of the new raster should be present and match the original. If using this tool (or similar tools which generate a new raster) you may need to use the [Build Raster Attribute Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m2000000) tool and then join/export or join field the original table to the new one. More information can be found in the help files for [Raster dataset attribute tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000009000000).

As suggested at [Preserve attribute table while using Extract by Mask in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112377/) you might use the [Clip tool under Raster Processing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009n000000) instead, which should do essentially the same thing and preserve the attributes. Note it may preserve *all* attribute values from the table, not just those present in the extracted/clipped area.